# Vectorising a double for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorise this double for loop which calculates co-ordinates, so I've got

```
A = zeros(100,100);  
for x = 1:100       
    for y = 1:100
        A(x,y) = x^2 + y  %or other functions with x and y
    end
end
```

Though trying to vectorise it by using something like meshgrid like some examples I've seen gives me a whole load of errors like "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."

Is there a way to vectorise this? Thanks very much for the help.

I'm actually using

```
A = zeros(31,31);
for x = 1:31       
    for y = 1:31
        A(y,x) = f(1.5, (x-16)/10 + i*((y-16)/10), 1000);
    end
end
```

where f(1.5,...) is some other function I'm using to calculate the points of A which would output just a number.

Trying something like

```
A = zeros(31,31);
[X,Y] = ndgrid(1:31,1:31);
A(Y,X) = f(1.5, (X-16)/10 + i*((Y-16)/10), 1000);
```

Gives me:

Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

An error in f

Error in line 3:
A(Y,X) = f(1.5, (X-16)/10 + i*((Y-16)/10), 1000);

Comment: Show your attempt code and exact details of the errors seen

Comment: You need to tell us what is that `func, f`.  Could you add it's implementation?

Answer (score 4):

Let `N = 100` be the datasize. You have few approaches here to play with.

**Approach #1: `bsxfun` with built-in `@plus`**

```
A = bsxfun(@plus,[1:N]'.^2,1:N)
```

**Approach #2: `bsxfun` with `anonymous function` -**

```
func = @(x,y) x.^2 + y 
A = bsxfun(func,[1:N]',1:N)
```

For a general function with `x` and `y`, you can use `ndgrid` or `meshgrid` as discussed next.

**Approach #3: With `ndgrid` -**

```
[X,Y] = ndgrid(1:N,1:N);
A =  X.^2 + Y
```

**Approach #4: With `meshgrid` -**

```
[Y,X] = meshgrid(1:N,1:N);
A =  X.^2 + Y
```